# SQL day syntax doesn't work on AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Complete SQL novice. I am trying to execute the following TPC-H query on AWS Athena:

```
select
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus,
        sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,
        sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as sum_disc_price,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) * (1 + l_tax)) as sum_charge,
        avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty,
        avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
        avg(l_discount) as avg_disc,
        count(*) as count_order
from
        lineitem
where
        l_shipdate <= date '1998-12-01' - interval ':1' day (3)
group by
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus
order by
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus;
```

Unfortunately Athena doesn't understand this synatx:
l_shipdate <= date '1998-12-01' - interval ':1' day (3)
Me neither. What is this trying to do?

Comment: What is `interval ':1' day`?  Do you mean `interval '1 day'`?

Comment: This is from the TPC-H official package. As stated in the question I have no idea what it means

Comment: I see :1 is a parameter. However, replacing it with 1 still fails AWS Athena query. The problem is I don't understand what the parenthesis after the interval 1 day is supposed to mean.

Comment: Same problem reported here, 16 years ago: [SQL - Unexpected Token "date/interval" - DB2 Database](https://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/184805-sql-unexpected-token-date-interval)